cppyy debugging with breakpoints
I'm trying to do mixed-mode debugging with cppyy, i.e., start from Python, call some C++ code with cppyy.include(), and hit a breakpoint there in C++.
The code runs fine, but unfortunately, I cannot achieve the IDE to stop at the C++ breakpoint.
I'm wondering if it is even possible this way, because there is no library in the background which may contain debug symbols, and in some cases (with cppyy.cppdef()) there is even no C++ source file on the disk, just a Python string.
I've read through the cppyy documentation, esp. https://cppyy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/debugging.html, also the linked https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/debugging-mixed-mode-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio for Visual Studio. EXTRA_CLING_ARGS environment variable is set to “-g -O2”.
I'm able to do this cppyy mixed-mode debugging both with Eclipse and Visual Studio (successfully hitting breakpoints) only if I create a DLL and use it via cppyy.load_library(), but none of these IDEs stop at breakpoints if I only include the C++ sources via cppyy.include().
So, what are the necessary steps to be able to hit breakpoints in C++ without library (DLL) in the background? Is it even possible? Is even cppyy.include() the right way of including sources, not just header files?
I’m on Windows 11, with Python 3.7.9 and cppyy-3.1.2.
(Thanks wlav in advance )

The main problem with JITed code is for the debugger to recognize it as executable code. If it isn't aware that some application memory may contain JITed code, it will not search there for locations to set breakpoints.
I don't develop on Windows so there may be better answers, but the few times that I needed to, I used WinDbg instead of VS and that worked.
(There's this thread on why WinDbg is generally better than VS; there might be some insights there as well as motivation for using that tool instead.)

I don't want to give this up, but I'm still stuck a bit.
I managed to step into the JITed C++ function with WinDbg (I called debugapi.h's DebugBreak()), but seemingly it does not see symbols or source there anymore -- call stack is like:
..
[0x3]  0x21777edb30!+        0x21777eda18
[0x4]  0x1!+        0x21777eda20
[0x5]  0x21777edb30!+        0x21777eda28
[0x6]  libcppyy_backend!Cppyy::Destruct+0x583        0x21777eda30
[0x7]  libcppyy_backend!Cppyy::CallV+0x21        0x21777edb80
..
Any hints for extra steps in WinDbg, so that I can see the JITed function name and add breakpoint?
